# Value associated with the case statement condition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I have two tables:
Item and Job
I'm trying to get the unit weight of the item from the item table.
The Job table has two item code columns. Item1, Item 2
I'm using something like this.

```
  CASE 
      WHEN job.item2 
      LIKE '%cc%'
      THEN item.unitweight * job.qty
      ELSE job.qty
      END AS specific item
```

Job Table

```
+-----+-------+-------+-----+
| job | Item1 | Item2 | qty |
+-----+-------+-------+-----+
|   1 | aa    | aaa   |   5 |
|   2 | bb    | cc    |   6 |
|   3 | cc    | bb    |   7 |
|   4 | aa    | ddd   |   8 |
+-----+-------+-------+-----+
```

Item Table

```
+------+-------------+
| Item | Unit Weight |
+------+-------------+
| aa   |           5 |
| bb   |           6 |
| cc   |           7 |
| dd   |           8 |
+------+-------------+
```

I want to get the query to return 42 associated with Item2 but my query returns 36

Comment: I don't really understand the result you want. Can you post a sample of the desired result and the one you are getting?

Comment: for job 2 you get 6 which is the value of bb but you'd rather have the value of cc which is 7? What's the join condition? Take Item 2 over item 1?

Comment: Can you post the whole query?

Comment: `aaa` and `ddd` don't have related values in the ITEM table.

Comment: *why* should your query return 42?   What is the logic behind that?

Comment: @scsimon : can i have the item2 over item1 only when the condition is satisfied?

Comment: Do you only want to use column `Item2` only? What about `Item1`? Shouldn't the result be 36 + 42 = 78?

Comment: @TabAlleman I'm trying to get the cc value from item table when the item2 is cc

Comment: Think I might've found a fault in your query. Check out my answer for more...

Comment: @MK_ you got it, thanks:)

Comment: @raider - so it works as expected now? That's great. Mark it as answered then so people know it has been solved. PS. don't forget you have the same kind of `CASE` logic on another place where you calculate `cost/unit_weight`. Check if you need to change it there too.

Comment: I corrected there already. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you want something like this?

```
SELECT j.job, j.Item1, j.Item2, j.qty
    , CASE
        WHEN j.Item2 = 'cc'  -- or do you want it to only have cc in it? then it would be LIKE '%cc%'
            THEN i2.unitweight * j.qty
        ELSE
            j.qty
      END
FROM Job j
    INNER JOIN Item i1 ON j.Item1 = i1.Item
    INNER JOIN Item i2 ON j.Item2 = i2.Item;
```

**EDIT:** Upon looking at your query, you might want to change `THEN ISNULL((item_mst.unit_weight * jobmatl_mst.matl_qty),0` into `THEN ISNULL((bitem.unit_weight * jobmatl_mst.matl_qty),0`. It appears you're simply multiplying by the wrong unit weights?

Answer (score 1):

Using my best interpretation of your question, I came up with this:

```
    SELECT  J.JOB, 
            CASE  WHEN J.ITEM1 = 'cc' 
                  THEN I1.Unit_Wt * j.QTY
                  ELSE 0
                  END 
                    + CASE  WHEN J.ITEM2 = 'cc' 
                            THEN I2.Unit_Wt * j.QTY
                            ELSE 0
                            END AS cc_tot_wt

    FROM    #Job AS J
            LEFT JOIN #Item AS I1
              ON I1.ITEM = J.ITEM1
            LEFT JOIN #Item AS I2
              ON I2.ITEM = J.ITEM2

    WHERE   I1.ITEM = 'cc' 
            OR I2.ITEM = 'cc'
```

This gives you an answer of 42 for Job 2 and 49 for Job 3, which are the total weights of item 'cc' for the job.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to get the `cc` value from `item` table when the `item2` is `cc`

You can do it by left-joining `item2` to your query:

```
SELECT
  ...
  CASE 
      WHEN job.item2 
      LIKE '%cc%'
      THEN i2.unitweight * job.qty -- Use i2.unweight
      ELSE job.qty
      END AS specific item
FROM job
JOIN item on item.Item=job.Item1
LEFT OUTER JOIN item i2 on i2.Item=job.Item2 -- Add this join
```